# Find the modo value

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, logarithms

I have given a **log value Y** , i want to calculate the anti log of Y i.e

$ans = Math.pow(10,Y)mod(1e9+7) $ the anti log of Y will always be integer i.e
Y is calculate as follow $Y= log(a)$   a is very large integer of range 10^100000

So for given Y i need to calculate ans ? How to do that considering the mod operation.

**My Approach**

```
double D = Y -(int)Y
long Pow = (long)Y

  for(int i=1;i<=Pow;i++) ans = (ans*10)%mod;

  ans = (ans*Math.pow(10,D))%mod
```

But it's not correct can someone suggest be efficient approach here ?

Comment: This is impractical. The logarithm value $Y$ of such a large number will not have the precision to give you the low-order digits of $10^Y$.

Comment: That $10^9+7$ is a typical Project Euler modulus. Are you sure you are not cheating in a contest?

Answer (score 0):

double frac = y-(int)y;
int power = (int)y;

**double val = (Math.pow(10,frac)*powerMod(10,power,mod))%mod;**

And the function powerMod(double val ,int power,int mod){
if(power==0) return 1;
else if (power%2) return powerMod(val*val,power/2,mod)%mod;
else return (val *powerMod(val,power-1,mod))%mod;
}

Comment: How to deal with floating point number Y can be floating point number

Comment: You make a base case when the power is less than 1 and bigger or equal 0

Comment: Can you please explain let say `Y=19.576047407193627`

Comment: Read the new code